# COUNT CASE function on a range of dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I trying to find an elegant solution for two problems:
I have an issue with the SELECT section on both questions.
The other part of the queries is fine

The questions are theoretically so no database available to run it on.

> **Q1**: Pull the following report: For each day show the accumulated
>   (moving) number of “likes” in the last 5 days inclusive (e.g.: May5th
>   will show the total likes from May 1st to May 5th.)  split to US vs.
>   Non-US geos.
>
> **Columns**:
>
> DataTimstamp - upper boundary of a 5-day time frame Total - number of
>   likes within the time frame  Region_US - number of likes where country
>   = 'US' Region_rest - number of likes where country<>'US'
>
> **Q2**: For each day pull the number of users created and the daily change
>   as compared to the day before.

**Code**:

```
SELECT 
       DATEADD(day, 4, se.date) AS DataTimstamp,
       COUNT(se.type_id) AS Total,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN lo.country_3_character_code = 'USA' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Region_USA',
       COUNT(CASE WHEN lo.country_3_character_code != 'USA' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS 'Region_rest'
  FROM  system_events se
  JOIN  location lo ON se.location_id = lo.id
  WHERE se.type = 'like'
GROUP BY 1

SELECT u.creation_date AS 'day', 
      COUNT(IF(day = u.creation_date, u.id, 0)) AS Date_day,
      COUNT(IF(day = u.creation_date - interval 1 day , u.id, 0)) AS Date_before,
      SUM(SUM(Date_day)-SUM(Date_before)) AS daily_change 
FROM user u
GROUP BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Q2 I think you can use LAG to get previous day e.g. this simple example:

```
with cte_table as
(
select * from
(values
   ('01-Jan-19',1)
  ,('02-Jan-19',2)
  ,('03-Jan-19',3)
  ,('04-Jan-19',4)
  ,('05-Jan-19',5)
) as t (TheDate,TheValue))

select TheDate, TheValue,
       LAG(TheValue,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY TheDate) as Prev_Value 
from cte_table;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Q1 last 5 days, I've taken a punt with this, I'll probably get eaten alive by the SQL Masters :-o, probably someway to do with cross apply but outside of my current knowledge.

```
with cte_table as
(
  select * from
    (values
     ('01-Jan-19',10)
    ,('02-Jan-19',20)
    ,('03-Jan-19',10)
    ,('04-Jan-19',5)
    ,('05-Jan-19',10)
    ,('06-Jan-19',20)
    ,('07-Jan-19',10)
    ,('08-Jan-19',10)
    ,('09-Jan-19',10)
    ,('10-Jan-19',5)
) as t (TheDate,TheValue))
, cte_table2 as
(
  select TheDate, TheValue
     ,LAG(TheValue,1,0) OVER(ORDER BY TheDate) as Prev_Value1 
     ,LAG(TheValue,2,0) OVER(ORDER BY TheDate) as Prev_Value2 
     ,LAG(TheValue,3,0) OVER(ORDER BY TheDate) as Prev_Value3 
     ,LAG(TheValue,4,0) OVER(ORDER BY TheDate) as Prev_Value4 
  from cte_table
)

 select TheDate
        ,sum(TheValue) as current_day
        , sum(TheValue) + sum(Prev_Value1) + sum(Prev_Value2) + sum(Prev_Value3) + sum(Prev_Value4) as [last 5 days]
 from cte_table2
 group by TheDate
 order by TheDate
 ;
```